# Flex 4 create validator that allows only letters and dashes?

Tags: validation, flex4

How can I create a validator that allows only letters as dashes as input?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is what I have so far..

If I write test it passes and if I write 123 it fails but if I write test123 it passes which I don't want

**EDIT**

The validator now works as I wanted. :)

```
override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array
        {
            results = [];

            var regEx:RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z _-]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z _-]*$/;

            if(regEx.test(value as String)) {
                trace("passed")
                return results;

            } else {
                var err:ValidationResult = new ValidationResult(true,"","","Only letters are allowed");
                results.push(err);
                trace("error")
            }

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the correct RE is `^[a-zA-Z _-]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z _-]*$`